# Java pattern to delimit string and find field

Tags: java, regex, split

I once again need some help with this as I cannot figure out how to get a regex going.

Heres the string I want to split:

```
String str = "ERR||||TEST|GET|POST|UPDATE|"
```

I have a function which given a field index starting with 1 will return the string at that position after splitting the string. However the problem is that the regex does not return the empty strings between the delimiters as this is counted towards the field index. How can I modify this regex to include these empty fields ?

```
private static String extractField(String strt, int fieldNo)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^|]+");
    String str = strt.replaceAll("\\r", "");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    int i = 1;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String fS = matcher.group().trim();
        System.out.println("Result: \"" + fS + "\"");
        if (i++==fieldNo) {
            return fS;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: You have "[^|]+" which matches the longest possible sequence of | - this means that the pattern doesn't see what occurs between the | if it is null. Change the pattern to "[^|]".

Comment: That will only return a single character. What I want is ERR,,,,TEST,GET,POST,UPDATE

Comment: Is it possible that your string will start with `|` like `"|ab||c|"`? In that case what should it first element? Would it be empty string `""` or `"ab"`?

Comment: no theres no possibility of it happening.

Comment: OK, so same question about data that ends with `|` like in your example `"...|POST|UPDATE|"`. Would last element be `"UPDATE"` or empty String `""`?

Comment: Yup theres a possibility of it being empty. This format is following the HL7 format. Its a healthcare message protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looking for a `Pattern`-based solution, you can use the regex:

```
(?<=(^|\|))(.*?)(?=(\||$))
```

Those are a positive lookahead (`(?=X)`) and a positive look-behind (`(?<=X)`). This mill match anything between two `|`s, or between the start of the string (`^`) and a `|`, or between a `|` and the end of the string (`$`). As lookaheads and look-behinds are zero-width assertions, they will not include the `|` in the groups. Also, the `?` in `.*?` makes it non-greedy.

**Code:**

```
private static String extractField(String strt, int fieldNo)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=(^|\\|))(.*?)(?=(\\||$))");
    String str = strt.replaceAll("\\r", "");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    int i = 1;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String fS = matcher.group().trim();
        System.out.println("Result: \"" + fS + "\"");
        if (i++==fieldNo) {
            return fS;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Results for `"ERR||||TEST|GET|POST|UPDATE|"`:

```
Result: "ERR"
Result: ""
Result: ""
Result: ""
Result: "TEST"
Result: "GET"
Result: "POST"
Result: "UPDATE"
Result: ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)? ...

```
String[] x = str.split("\\|");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I realize you can use split for this. But Id like to know how to use Pattern regex as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a split on | would yield what you want.

Something like this:

```
    String s = "ERR||||TEST|GET|POST|UPDATE|";
    String [] a = s.split("\\|");
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I realize you can use split for this. But Id like to know how to use Pattern regex as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily upgrade your regex using [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism.
Try maybe this way `[^|]+|(?<=[|])`. Additional part `|(?<=[|])` means *"OR empty string that have* `|` *before it"*.

Thanks to this regex for `ERR||||TEST|GET|POST|UPDATE|` you will find

```
"ERR", "", "", "", "TEST", "GET", "POST", "UPDATE", ""
```

---

In case you don't want last `""` you may use `[^|]+|(?<=[|])(?=[|])`. `(?<=[|])(?=[|])` means *"empty string that exists between two* `|`*"*, so result of this pattern will be

```
"ERR", "", "", "", "TEST", "GET", "POST", "UPDATE"
```